# What gcloud command can be used to obtain a list of default compute engine service accounts across your organisation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have tried this command;

`gcloud alpha scc assets list <ORGANISATION-ID> --filter "security_center_properties.resource.type="google.iam.ServiceAccount" AND resource_properties.name:\"Compute Engine default service account\""`

but I am recieving the following error;

`(gcloud.alpha.scc.assets.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid filter.`

When I remove the filter after `AND`, I don't get an error message but I just see an `>`

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

I have reviewed [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/scc/assets/list) documentation to support me building the command but not sure which is the right filter to use.

I wonder if i should be filtering on the email of a compute engine default service account that ends "-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" but I can't identify what the right filter for this is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of `"` on the filter.

You need to type `--filter` and put the filter like this:  `"FILTER_EXPRESION"`.

One filter expression could be: `security_center_properties.resource_type="google.compute.Instance"`

But you can not put a double quote inside a double quote block. So you need to use the back slash (`\`),if not,  the command interpret the first double quote of the filter as the end of the filter.

On the other hand if you delete part of the command the prompt shows you '>' because there is a double quote block that is not end and it is waiting that you ends the command.

So the filter that you want has to be like this, for example:

```
gcloud alpha scc assets list <ORGANIZATION ID> \
--filter "security_center_properties.resource_type=\"google.compute.Instance\" AND security_center_properties.resource_type=\"google.cloud.resourcemanager.Organization\""
```

I hope that this explanation could help you!